# nth-child(even) doesn't work, but odd work

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a css for `.st--player-box`, that even numbers had value `float: right;`, and odd numbers had a `float: left;`

```
<div class="st--players-container">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="st--player-box">...</div>
        </a>
            <a href="#">
            <div class="st--player-box">...</div>
        </a>
            <a href="#">
            <div class="st--player-box">...</div>
        </a>
            <a href="#">
            <div class="st--player-box">...</div>
        </a>
</div>
```

I make a this code in CSS, but I don't know, why this is doesn't work.

```
.st--players-container .st--player-box {
  display: block;
  width: -webkit-calc(47%);
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.st--players-container .st--player-box:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}
.st--players-container .st--player-box:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: All `<div class="st--player-box">` are first children within their `<a>`, so they are all odd children. Did you mean `.st--players-container > a:nth-child(odd) > .st--player-box`?

Comment: yes add nth-child to <a> tag

Answer (score 1):

Because `div.st--player-box` is not root child of `div.st--players-container`. You need to target root child element `<a>...</a>`

```
.st--players-container .st--player-box {
  display: block;
  width: -webkit-calc(47%);
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.st--players-container a:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}
.st--players-container a:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
```

Here is an working [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vqcr61fw/)